# CanDropLabels on Axis reesizing Highcharts similar to Flex ActionScript

Tags: actionscript-3, highcharts

Horizontal Axis Labels Should Adjust on Resize of Highcharts.

Assume we have values of Horizontal Axis as A , B , C , D , E and we resize the chart to make it small then in that case my horizontal axis show only A , C , E

B and C are dropped

Comment: it is adjusting in Highcharts, try to change the size of your chart here: http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/line-basic/

Comment: I am resizing browser window so in turn my chart resizes. so do we have some option where it will automatically drop horizontal axis labels

Comment: Thanks Grzegorz  actually we had specified step hence the labels were not getting dropped. After removing step value it is working